# how to display images in imageview in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

Iam new to iphone currently my problem is

i displayed 6 images in 6 image views It was not showing images in imageview I think the imageviews are in large size

i implement code like this.

```
imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wolf.jpg"];
[imageview2 setImage:img1];
```

so plz send me correct code for this imageview.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: It's important to accept answers to your questions. Please go back to your other questions where you received a useful answer and click the gray checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Did any of these answers work out for you? Please accept one by clicking on the gray checkmark next to the answer if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're adding the image **1** to imageview **2** - are you sure you want to do this?

Secondly, you need to add the imagview to the view hierarchy, for example by adding it to a ViewControllers view, like this: `[[self view] addSubview:imageview1]` (If this code is situated within the View Controller class).

Answer (score 7):

```
bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,480,300)];
bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
[self.view addSubview:bgImage];
```

Also check have you add image file to your project, by Add - > Existing File

Answer (score 0):

```
imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wolf.jpg"];
```